# Can momentum exist in a null direction?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, momentum, metric-tensor, vectors

CONTEXT (skip to "my question is"):

As I understand it, *and correct me if I'm wrong,* an orbit trades momentum between the X and Y directions. But spacetime can have negative and even null directions.

Relativistic length contraction is rotation into a direction that has negative magnitude in the metric: *time*. Relativistic length contraction (which looks like acceleration in 3D), is actually just ordinary foreshortening, like the shadow of a rotating pencil. Relativistic time dilation is the same phenomenon. Extent in space is traded for extent in time.

Interesting distraction: Viewed from the side, a candle on the edge of a rotating disk appears to accelerate continuously, back and forth. In fact, rotation in $n$ dimensions *always* looks like acceleration in $n-1$ dimensions.

But *null* directions may also exist. Every line extending into a null direction has length zero. But it is unclear to me what happens to any momentum that an object rotating into that dimension may have. Does it exist infinitesimally?

MY QUESTION IS:

Can momentum be exchanged between a timelike direction and a null one?

That is, can an object rotate into a null direction — with its momentum vector pointing only in that dimension for a moment — then bleed its momentum back into timelike direction with the sine of the angle it now extends into timelike direction?

Just providing a link would be a great response. You don't have to spend time patiently explaining group theory to another bewildered padawan.

Comment: In my experience, physicists don’t talk about null *dimensions*; try googling “null dimension” (with parens) to see this. (Your use of this phrase may or may not have been why a moderator considered the question to be non-mainstream physics.) You can have null directions in spacetime, null four-vectors, null spacetime intervals, etc. but none of these things are “dimensions”.

Comment: There are no “negative dimensions” either. The fact that Lorentzian metrics have negative terms doesn’t mean that dimensions are negative. Since misuse of terminology can be either inadvertent or intentional, it can sometimes be hard to distinguish a physics enthusiast who is still learning from a crank peddling some pet personal theory.

Comment: I think this question is being treated unnecessarily harshly. Both with downvotes and closure votes.

Comment: Any extent into dimension 1 in signature (3,1) _decreases_ the interval between two events. If referring to that dimension as "negative" causes a question to be closed as a  "personal theory," then this forum -- while invaluable to research -- is an unintentional impediment to learning, and serious students have to go elsewhere to understand spacetime. While you need to filter out the crazy "aether" theories, I  believe this filter is over-tuned. It drives away serious students, and is not in the interest of either education or science.

Comment: Someone voted this  to minus 1, so I will probably be banned for asking,"Can momentum exist in a null dimension?" That's it. No assertions, just the question. Make your own evaluation. Was it a stupid question? Was it a "personal theory?" This happens a lot. Is there another site where people discuss this -- a hobo village of smart people who were shunned for reasons we can compare, with links to our offending posts? I'd be interested to see if there are patterns.

Comment: You are being overly defensive. It is very plausible that the question also got closed simply because its abuse of terminology makes it very unclear and therefore rather hard to even answer. This is not generally a discussion site. It is a professional forum where questions of varying levels of complexity are answered in a generally authoritative way.

Comment: " the question also got closed simply because its abuse of terminology" So I don't do it again, was this abuse my referring to n in (3,n,1) a "negative dimension?"  If so, what would an acceptable name be? I detect that maybe its impolite to ask, but I can just barely detect social context like that.

Comment: Your question was reopened after a moderator fixed the terminology. You can see the edits by clicking on the “edited … ago” link.

Comment: The short answer to the question in the title is that the momentum of massless particles (like photons) always points in a null direction.

Comment: Do you know about “accepting” answers? You have an upvoted answer that you haven’t accepted. This indicates to Dale that you don’t think it answers your question. If you think it *does* answer your question, you should accept it. If you think it doesn’t, you should tell him why in a comment on his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Momentum is conserved component wise. Each component is separate and is individually conserved. You cannot trade momentum between x and y directions.

So to directly answer the question:

> Can momentum be exchanged between a real dimension and a null one?

No. Momentum cannot be exchanged between directions at all. Not even between spatial directions, and certainly not between null and spatial or temporal directions.

What you can do is transfer momentum from one system to another. One system can lose x momentum and another can gain that x momentum. But the x momentum that one system has cannot turn into y momentum in that system nor can it turn into y momentum during the transfer to another system.

An object, like a pulse of light, that has null momentum has components of momentum both in some spatial direction (e.g. x) and in the t direction (t momentum is energy). The amount of momentum in both directions is equal in units where $c=1$.

If that momentum is absorbed by another system then that system will gain both the t momentum and the x momentum removed from the light. That does not mean that the receiving object will become null. It only means that the x and t components of the light’s momentum will be transferred to the absorbing system

Comment: You said "You cannot trade momentum between x and y directions". Does it true for electromagnetic field? Does the balance equation for the field momentum allow to change between field momentum components?

Comment: @Sancol. it is also true for the electromagnetic field. As far as I know it is universally true in flat spacetime